# REACT useEffect() called unwanted

Tags: reactjs, components, use-effect

I'm using `useEffect` which should update my component whenever the value `selected` of my state updates:

```
const Thumbnail = ({ image }) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(getChecked());

    useEffect(() => {
        setChecked(getChecked())
    }, [state.selected])

...

}
export default Thumbnail
```

But the Function is called everytime anything in my state is updated. For example when an other component updates `state.all`, the `useEffect()` method is being called.

How can I avoit this and only call the `useEffect()` method when `state.selected` is being changed?

Comment: what is the type of `state.selected`? if it's not a primitive it's reference might change causing the effect to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

`useMemo` will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed.

`const checked = useMemo(() => getChecked(), [state.selected]);`